# Pass selected <option> in <select> tag to next page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a  using following code

```
<select name="Books">
<% books.each do |book| %>
<option value="<%= book.id%>"> <%= book.name %> </option>
</select>
<% end %>
```

I have a button on the same page

```
<button>View Book Details</button>
<button>Delete Book</button>
```

Now I want to take user to different pages depending upon the button he clicks.
Say when he clicks on "View Book Details", I want to land him to `/book/view`
and if he clicks on "Delete Book", I want to land him to `/book/delete`

When I land user to the desired page, I want to pass the  selected by user using  to the landing page. Something like this

- Say, if user choose Book-**1**, and clicks on "View Book Details", I want
  `/book/view?id=1`
- if user choose Book-**3**, and clicks on "View Book Details", I want
  `/book/view?id=3`
- if user choose Book-**5**, and clicks on "Delete Book", I want
  `/book/delete?id=5`

**How can I do this ?**

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, I could come up with this:

```
 <%= form_tag "/book/view", method: :get do %>
   <%= select_tag "id", options_for_select(books.collect{|book| ["#{book.name} #{book.id}", book.id] }) %>
   <%= submit_tag "View Book Details" %>
 <% end %>

 <%= form_tag "/book/delete", method: :delete do %>
   <%= select_tag "id", options_for_select(books.collect{|book| ["#{book.name} #{book.id}", book.id] }) %>
   <%= submit_tag "Delete Book" %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: So, here you are creating two combo boxes for user on screen. Can't it be done with single combo box (single select)?

Comment: @SimpleGuy, you can do this by using hidden element and single select. Keep one hidden field for each form representing select and update them when value of select changes.

Comment: @maximus Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @SimpleGuy added new answer for your ease.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single select and single hidden field to make this work.

```
 //form 1 for view 
 <%= form_tag "/book/view", method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag "id", options_for_select(books.collect{|book| ["#{book.name} #{book.id}", book.id] }), 
     :onChange => "$('#book_select').val($(this).val())" %>
  <%= submit_tag "View Book Details" %>
 <% end %>

 //form 2 for delete
 <%= form_tag "/book/delete", method: :delete do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "book_select", :name => "id" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Delete Book" %>
 <% end %>
```